# How to change the argument of a function in a onclick property on a <img> tag?

Tags: javascript, html

So, I call a function inline inside an img tag onclick, and when it performed its task, I want that function call to change the second property of a function inside another img tags onclick property, the only way I can think of doing that is reading the onclick property's string, scanning from the right for the first ' to appear, reading everything till the next ' into a variable and change that.

Here's my javascript

```
function hideShow(x,y) {
    var hide = document.getElementById(x);
    var show = document.getElementById(y);
    if (!hide.classList.contains("display-none") && show.classList.contains("display-none")) {
        hide.classList.add("display-none");
        show.classList.remove("display-none");
    } else {
        hide.classList.remove("display-none");
        show.classList.add("display-none");
    }
}
```

And the html

```
<img src="img/label1.png" class="cursor-pointer" onClick="hideShow('label1','label2')" id="label1">
<img src="img/label2.png" class="cursor-ponter display-none" onClick="hideShow('label2','label3')" id="label2">
<img src="img/label3.png" class="cursor-pinter display-none" onClick="hideShow('label3','label1')" id="label3">
```

Now I wish I knew a more simple way of changing the second argument of the function inside the first img-tags onclick-property to 'label3', when I click the third img.

Comment: When you click each image, what should happen? Can you explain a bit?

Comment: @Aruna it calls the function inside the onClick-property of the element and that function hides the element referenced by id in the first argument, and shows the element referenced by id in the second argument.

Comment: And what issue currently you have?

Comment: @Aruna as stated in the OP, "...changing the second argument of the function inside the first img-tags onclick-property to 'label3', when I click the third img."

Comment: Okay I got it. Will post the answer.

Comment: Can you check my answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the code as you expected.

Instead of passing the second argument in the function, its maintained in the attribute and when required on the click of third image, this attribute can be changed inside the function.

```js
function hideShow(x, changeAttr) {
    var attrKey = 'data-element';
    var hide = document.getElementById(x);
    var show = document.getElementById(attr(hide, attrKey));
    if (!hide.classList.contains("display-none") && show.classList.contains("display-none")) {
        hide.classList.add("display-none");
        show.classList.remove("display-none");
    } else {
        hide.classList.remove("display-none");
        show.classList.add("display-none");
    }
  
   if(changeAttr) {
     attr(show, attrKey, x);
   }
}

function attr(elm, attrName, attrValue) {
  attrValue = attrValue || '';
  if (elm.hasAttributes()) {
       var attrs = elm.attributes;
       for(var i = 0; i < attrs.length; i++) {
         if(attrs[i].name === attrName) { 
           if(attrValue) {
             attrs[i].value = attrValue;
           } else {
             attrValue = attrs[i].value;
           }
           
           break;
         }
       }
     } 
  
  return attrValue;
}
```

```css
.display-none {
  display: none;
}

.cursor-pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<img src="img/label1.png" class="cursor-pointer" onClick="hideShow('label1')" data-element="label2" id="label1">
<img src="img/label2.png" class="cursor-pointer display-none" onClick="hideShow('label2')" data-element="label3" id="label2">
<img src="img/label3.png" class="cursor-pointer display-none" onClick="hideShow('label3', true)" data-element="label1" id="label3">
```

Comment: I cant figure out what the OP is actually trying to do, yet this example will make the second image inaccessable after the first full 'chain'.

Answer (score 0):

Make a globally scoped variable with the default value of the second argument (for each of the images onclick event that you wish).

When the function runs as a result of clicking the first image, the function changes that globally scoped variable.

Now, when the second image is clicked, the 2nd argument has the value set by that previous function, or, if that first image wasn't clicked, still has the default value you set when creating the globally scoped variable.

Comment: If I'm correct, a global variable will stay in the environment till the page is left right?

Comment: @J.H. Yes, just add your variables in the header of your page in a script